# Ummm what day was it, a matchstick puzzle

Tags: matches

```
      XXIII  
     -------  =  II  
       VII
```

All you need to do is move one matchstick from the roman numerals to make the equation true.

Comment: move or remove?

Comment: @question_asker move...

Comment: I remember this one from when I was a kid (40 odd years ago), great seeing it here!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could move...

> The last **I** from the numerator onto the top of the result, like so:
>
>  XXII
>  ---- = $\pi$
>  VII
>  It's an approximation, but yesterday was Pi Day.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Both the reasoning and the answer ^_^

Comment: So "yesterday" is close enough? When is the cutoff that this answer would no longer be appropriate? :P

Comment: @ttt it will always be yesterday relative to the posting of the question

Comment: @question_asker, I meant, if this question was asked 6 months from now, I don't think the answer would be correct since 22/7 does not equal pi. (6 months from now you wouldn't say, 22/7 = pi and pi day is March 14. At least I don't think I would say that...)

Comment: @ttt but the question isn't posted six months from now, it was posted today

Comment: @question_asker - I know that. But for fun, I'm just wondering when the cutoff would be. I think tomorrow would be fine, maybe even the next day or any day this week. Next month, probably not. Can you draw a line in the sand and say, "This is a good answer if the question is asked within X days of pi day." I wonder what X is.

Comment: @ttt I get what you're saying but I think the answer is that any day is a good day as long as you incorporate [integral part of the answer] into the question somehow. It doesn't have to be *about* the day

Comment: @TTT "Yesterday" will always be assumed to be "yesterday at the time of writing" (equal to the day before the post was written), and since these posts are all timestamped, there's no problem.

Comment: @jpmc26, I must be explaining this poorly. I'm just curious about a psychological experiment. How far from pi day could this question have been asked so that it would still be considered a good question? I'm suggesting the answer might be about 3-5 days...

Comment: @TTT Do you want the question to be renamed as "What day was it yesterday" :-P

Comment: @ABcDexter Please let's not. Though there is a fair point here somewhere about the possibility of leaving the relative date out entirely and otherwise obliquely hinting at it.

Comment: @question_asker, Yes exactly. That is why I didn't do it at the first place. And by the way, this question was asked in a puzzling competition here :-)

Comment: @ABcDexter - if you renamed the question it would have been far too easy! I like it the way you have it.

Comment: Yesterday could also be acceptable on July 23, (which, in Europe, at least, would be 22/7).

Comment: Works fine for today ^-^

Answer (score 17):

If in “make the equation true”
only the words *make* and *true* are taken literally:

> XXII
>  
>  ——   ≠   II
>  
>    VII
>  
>  As [quintopia points out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/ummm-what-day-was-it-a-matchstick-puzzle/29007?noredirect=1#comment86138_29007),
>  this is no longer an equation.
>  (A deserved custard $\pi$ in my face.)

Comment: Well, that would go into the `lateral-thinking` part ;-)

Comment: Hahahahahaha.  Well played!

Comment: Is an inequality considered a equation?

Comment: Too true, @quintopia, the answer now includes a duly credited disclaimer. (As a matter of fact, to make the original equation true would require, more than moving a match, redefining the symbols used.)

Answer (score 12):

I think I'm allowed to:

> X\III
> ------ = II
> VII
>  It's hard to tell, but I removed part of an 'X' to make a single piece (placing the spare piece in the division sign), showing an informal "14". 14 divided by 7 equals 2.

*shrug*
"proof"

> "XXIII" is 23 and consists of 7 "sticks", where each "X" is two sticks. The division sign is made of 5 sticks (possibly just a coincidence, but "meh"). The "VII" is 7 and consists of 4 "sticks, where each "V" is represented by two sticks. 
>  
>  Remove one stick from the second X in "XXIII" to create "XIIII" (7-1 sticks) and place that stick in the division sign (which now consists of 5+1 sticks).

Comment: But you moved two matchsticks!

Comment: @ABcDexter how? I moved half of the 'X' (which consists of two matches). Unless I copied it wrong, which is possible.

Comment: This was actually my first thought, and the reason I asked the question I did in the comments

Comment: Where did the `I` of the 23 go? You placed the spare piece in the division sign right.

Comment: @ABcDexter yes. the "spare" piece is in the division sign (which is composed of several "sticks" in your example). That leaves an 'X' and four 'I's, though, one of them is a bit crooked.

Comment: Ok, but again, you needed to move exactly one stick :-)

Comment: @ABcDexter. (this textblock reads aggressively and that is not what I was going for) Am I typing what I'm trying to say wrong? Can someone please chime in? I'll try one more time to explain what I'm saying: please see the edit.

Comment: @goodguy5 Ok, understood and upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

> XXIII
>   ----- = II
>   VII

can be changed to become...

> XXIII
> ----- > II
> VII

in which...

> I slightly move one of the sticks in the equals sign to become a greater-than sign.  Because I cannot visually represent it, the top line will be angled downward to meet its bottom compatriot.  Like so, but reversed: ∠