# Make a square with matchsticks!

Tags: matches

After the previous [mat(c)h-stick puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/29004/1766), this one is relatively [old](http://matchstickpuzzles.blogspot.in/2016/07/406-hidden-square.html).

[image: The matchsticks]

Move **only one matchstick** to make a square.

Comment: Nice puzzle. I have to say that I like *both* of the answers below, which makes the puzzle ill-defined, i.e. bad. Going to DV.... Just kidding. I keep that one in memory ;c)

Comment: Thanks, i was just going through my questions and recalled this puzzle i had once thought of whilst playing with matchsticks :D

Comment: What do you mean relatively new? New for you maybe, but not a new puzzle. Maybe even new to be online, but I would be surprised. I first saw this puzzle over a decade ago. I think in a book belonging to my grandmother. With @rgthree's answer

Comment: I will one-up @Oxinabox and say I heard about this puzzle at least 20 years ago as a kid. So, no, not new by most definitions of the word.

Comment: @Oxinabox Ok, i think this is an old question so am updating the question.

Comment: @nitro2k01, indeed. I can attest that I learned this one from my great granddad, as he always liked to be the smart one in the room. He said he learned it in the first WW (trying to win drinks). Not sure it’s true, but it makes it an old trick for sure!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer is:

> Move the left pointing stick slightly to the left so it's right end edge meets the other matchsticks' ends forking a square in the negative space.
>
>  [image]

Comment: And gone in a jiffy :)

Answer (score 62):

> Move the right-most match to a diagonal between the top and left matches, making a 4, a square (number)

Comment: You're absolutely correct :)

Comment: While this is clever, since a match length is less than the diagonal, this doesn't really work. See a picture like http://i.stack.imgur.com/9bOZ4.png

Comment: @MarkS.; well it sort of works:), anyway you can stick up vertically from the tip of left match to get an LED 4, or even claim its a nine

Comment: @MarkS. Looks fine to me. I don't think that anyone will have difficulty recognizing your figure as a 4, just as people can read [these fonts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stencil+font&tbm=isch) without any trouble.

Comment: @MarkS. It didn't state that the matches needed to be touching

Comment: @MarkS. Or just arrange them in calculator fashion.

Answer (score 28):

The answer:

> A match is easy to break [image: The answer]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, nice out-of-the-box thinking!

Comment: but impossible to break in HALF?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry [It is possible](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Fuk-DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=how+to+break+matchstick+in+half&source=bl&ots=VKSZ_Wy_sw&sig=C_O4irJwBjRqGxjUEYyMzJ-lEFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2hs3Sm6DOAhWEwI8KHViOBXUQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20break%20matchstick%20in%20half&f=false), isn't it?

Comment: If impossible to break in half, also impossible to build exact-length and exact-width matches, so no square-making solution has a non-zero probability.

Comment: Even if it wasn't broken perfectly in half, the longer end could stick out some.

Comment: If you allow breaking the match, you can make any number of squares. :)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Although there is nothing like infinitesimal accuracy when it comes to do things with bare hands, but this `lateral-thinking` should suffice :D

Answer (score 10):

> Pick up one matchstick and look at the "safe" end. It's a square. (Generally)

or...

> Move any of the sticks however you like. Then pick up a pencil and draw a square.

or...

> Pick up a fifth matchstick and use it to light all sticks. If done on the right paper you now have a cross-shaped hole in the paper, creating four flaps. Fold back the flaps. The resulting hole is a square.

Comment: Light the match and use the burnt match to write C.  C is the square of X in roman numerals.

Comment: Or take the barometer to the building's superintendent and say "Hello Mr XYZ, I have here a very fine barometer, which I would gladly give to you if you will tell me the height of this building."

Comment: Your first and third answers are clever but I don't see how the second one is "moving a matchstick to make a squaare". The use of the preposition "to" (rather than, say, the conjunction "and") implies that the movement of the matchstick causes the square to come into existence. Your second solution moves a matchstick and creates a square but there is no causal relationship between them.

Comment: @FlorianF, you guys took it too far

Comment: I would like to see more of this.

Answer (score 2):

Select any matchstick to create a triangle, the write out formula for pythagoreans theorem A^2+B^2=C^2, the answer will result with (C) being **SQUARED.**

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.se]! This question isn't marked [lateral-thinking] so this is not likely to be a valid solution.