# Make 37+32=55 correct by moving one match

Tags: matches

[image: 37+32=55]

Move $1$ match and make this correct.

**Rules: (added 8/23/2018 based on clarifications in comments)**

- You can't break the match.
- You can't make an inequality sign, just change numbers and/or operators.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what kind of answers are acceptable? I was about to make the same suggestion as El-Guest, but he got there first.

Comment: @F1Krazy it's my famous CheaterPants-you-can't-do-that solution :)

Comment: my sister said //dont break the match, dont make inequality sign, just change numbers or operator//

Comment: Maybe greater than sign. Although this is probably cheating too.

Comment: @underds Would you mind providing a source for this problem, since it is not your own?

Comment: @BennettBernardoni I like that answer, although technically the equals sign is only an operator for computer science when it is used to set the value of a variable. In the context above, the equals sign is not an operator I don't think.

Comment: Anything workable by rotating the paper to approximately get `55=2E+LE"?

Comment: @El-Guest i already tried to find the source but couldnt find and my sister also doesnt know the source neither

Comment: My answer is in a way similar to "Super easy" by peaceoutside. Move the vertical line of + to make a comma between the two fives. In C and related languages a comma throws away the value of the first expression and returns the second one. So 5,5 makes 5. Or you could consider the comma as a decimal comma (instead of a decimal point in some countries), then it's only wrong by 1/2. (I don't have enought reputation to post this as an answer.)

Comment: Any restrictions about the number base? E.g., how about: 37 + 32 (octal) = 57 (decimal), by turning the last 5 into a funky 7 (move the middle matchstick in the last 5 to a vertical on the top right)? Similarly, 37 + 32 (hex) = 55 (decimal), so just pick up any matchstick, and just put it back.

Comment: @El-Guest This seems to be a cropped version of a picture from a Korean book: http://inven.co.kr/mobile/board/powerbbs.php?come_idx=4538&p=6&l=4466171 I don't speak Korean though :)

Comment: I feel like match could mean *pair*

Comment: Is there actually a known (and valid) solution?

Comment: If you turn the equal sign in to a plus sign the expression will evaluate to true in a JavaScript console...

Comment: Yes, @KevinFichter playing with the base was my thought too. Couldn't stop seeing Es once I turned it upside down.

Comment: @underds, does the book this comes out of actually provide a solution?

Comment: Is it anything to do with the number of matches that form each character?  3, 2 and 5 have 5 matches, but 4 only has 4 matches?

Comment: Sorry its not a 4 its a 7. Kind of lateral thinking but... Is it anything to do with the number of matches that form each character?  3, 2 and 5 have 5 matches, but 7 only has 4 matches? So move the horizontal match from the plus sign to the figure 7 so that each character has 5 matches each. So the image(not numbers) is now 5(matches)5 - 55 = 55. Remove(minus) two of the characters (10 matches) and you are left with 55

Comment: I don't think the following counts as an answer, but...
$$37+32=55$$ $$\Downarrow$$
$$37−32\neq 55$$
And we are done! (This uses the same approach as [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/ummm-what-day-was-it-a-matchstick-puzzle/29007#29007).) And if there was only one other match, or I could move *two* matches instead of one, I could make $97-32=65$ :D

Comment: Has the answer been posted?

Comment: getting closer to the source: https://twitter.com/oniontaker/status/1030460921917845504 with google translation (from Korean): "Matchstick Puzzle" "I have listed another expression. I made an Arabic number with a matchstick and then moved one matchstick to fix it."

Comment: `37 - 32 ≡ 55` which is `5 ≡ 55` (mod 50)

Comment: @user477343 I haven't read the other solutions but this one, changing the equal to "not equal", is basically what I came up with in about 5 seconds : )

Comment: @CedricMartin which is why I don't think it is the answer. I think it might be best if the puzzle included that it is not the intended answer :)

Comment: @zamnuts post that congruence observation as an answer! :P

Comment: @zamnuts The link I gave above ([the Korean site](http://inven.co.kr/mobile/board/powerbbs.php?come_idx=4538&p=6&l=4466171)) is older than that tweet. Actually, I found it by doing an image search from it.

Comment: @zamnuts To avoid the falseness of it, leave the plus there and just change one of the other numbers to gibberish.  Then you can have like 37 + (fake symbol) 2 ≡ 55.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this transcription & translation? - "성냥개비로 아라비아 숫자를 만들어 다음과 같이 다른 식을 나열하였습니다. 성냥개비 1개를 이동시켜 맞는 으 로식 고치시l요." => "I made an Arabic number with a matchstick and listed another expression like this: I moved one matchstick to fix it." - I don't think there's an issue with misinterpreting singular vs. plural here - it very clearly say the number one. However, a couple characters don't exactly fit, does the textbook just use a weird font?

Comment: I think the titles at the top say - "사고력 스팀 수악" => "Thinking Power Steam" & "성냥개비 퍼즐" => "Matchstick puzzle"

Comment: Check it out, there's a Korean Facebook post on this as well - https://www.facebook.com/SNUBamboo/photos/pb.560898400668463.-2207520000.1535039091./1956727191085570/?type=3&theater - the first comment reply (ordered by relevance) uses my rot13(ovgjvfr BE) solution, heh.

Comment: This comes from a Korean educational book, STEAM is Science Technology Engineering Arts & Math (much like Americans use STEM). There are definitely books for kids, but I can't tell if there are more advanced ones that would require knowledge of rot13(ovgjvfr bcrengbef)

Comment: @peaceoutside Yes, it does look like a book for a younger audience. As far as I can grok this, STEAM emphasizes the "Connection to the Real World", so it is possible that the solution might not be purely mathematical. So, setting matches on fire and/or folding the page in the middle of the 55 could all be valid solutions...

Comment: Considering that this problem comes from a Korean book, does the answer involve creating a Korean glyph/character?

Answer (score 66):

Super easy:

> 37 - 32 = 5 | 5

Where:

> the | is bitwise OR operator

By:

> moving the vertical match from the plus sign to the middle of the 55

Comment: I have a feeling this is technically the correct answer per the move one match stick requirement.

Comment: Which is, of course, the best kind of correct.

Comment: I know you mean `37 - 32 = (5 | 5)`, but I cannot help seeing it as `(37 - 32 = 5) | 5`, but maybe because that is because I am used to a programming language with a particular convention for operator precedence. I like the interpretation that `5 | 5` means `5` divides `5` (evenly), better.

Comment: I initially thought of this answer by considering the divisor operator (which is also commonly displayed as a | character). However, I have never really used that operator in practice, but I use bitwise operators all the time.

Comment: @Jeppe, which language? In C, `|` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: @GregSchmit In C, `=` is simple assignment which is not that relevant here. So I see the equality relation as corresponding to `==` in C, and `==` has higher precedence than `|`. In other words, in C, `37 - 32 = 5 | 5` makes little sense because you cannot assign to that, and `37 - 32 == 5 | 5` is legal and equivalent to `(37 - 32 == 5) | 5`.

Comment: @Jeppe I get that; however the symbol actually used is `=`, so it looks perfectly natural from another fellow programmer :)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen To be fair, `(37 - 32 == 5) | 5` equals to `true` anyways. So it's still technically correct.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the precedence thing. If it weren't for that I would've liked this answer the most, even though it's unlikely that that Korean riddle book uses programming operators. But I'm upvoting anyway, because I think it's a creative answer nonetheless. :-)

Comment: Jeppe is possibly a Smalltalk programmer. In Smalltalk, the "=" method is just another method, not different from the "-" or "|" method (the "=" tests for equality, an assignment would be ":="). Therefore, the expression would be processed strictly from left to right. You can try the code **Transcript show: (37-32=5|5) printString.** for your self on: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php

Answer (score 63):

A little of a stretch but

> $87 - 32 = 55$

by

> moving the upright + matchstick to the left of the 3 in 37

Comment: Pun not intended, but great anyway

Comment: Stretch, as in stretching the matchstick? (+1 from me) _Edit: but you got the upvote because of the sweet pun!_

Comment: You must hold the match closer to your face to see it span the whole number.

Comment: @tyobrien : indeed, the question doesn't specify you can only move it in two dimensions!

Comment: The funkily-drawn number solution is not unique. Remove the bottom match from the last 5, resulting in a funky 9. Use this match to change the first 5 into a 6, resulting in `37+32=69`.

Comment: This, and only this: It obeys all rules, and I never saw a match - question where matches had different sizes...

Answer (score 62):

Technically, you could change this to

> $37 - 32 \neq 55$

by

> moving the cross stick in the plus sign to go diagonally across the equals sign.

Comment: Well if that were true you could also rot13(zbir bar sebz gur rdhnyf fvta gheavat svsgl svir vagb avargl svir; guvf jbhyq or gehr fvapr rkcerffvbaf ner arvgure gehr abe snyfr)!

Comment: That sounds like another variation of the CheaterPants-You-Can't-Do-That solution, I like it!

Comment: It looks even better if you rot13(zbir gur yrsg fgvpx va gur bqq-ybbxvat frira gb sbez gur vardhnyvgl fvta.)

Comment: That way you could solve any match puzzle involving numbers.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: @PerpetualJ: That would violate the premise of the puzzle, rot13("znxr pbeerpg" vaureragyl vzcyvrf n "gehr" fgngr).

Comment: @Flater Saying rot13("Gjb cyhf gjb qbrf abg rdhny svir" vf n gehr, pbeerpg fgngrzrag.  ) . If that's a restriction the puzzle requires, it should say so.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: You're countering a point I never made. Rot13(CrecrghnyW'f fhttrfgvba eryvrf ba uvf fbyhgvba orvat "arvgure gehr abe snyfr", juvpu pbasyvpgf jvgu gur punyyratr juvpu nfxf gb "znxr vg pbeerpg". "Pbeerpg" vzcyvrf "gehr". Fbzrguvat gung pnaabg or gehr gurersber pnaabg or rinyhngrq gb or pbeerpg.)

Comment: @Flater Misunderstood what you were replying to--you're correct

Answer (score 53):

Just to prove that this is impossible (without some creativity), I wrote a python script to solve these:

```
subs = {'1':[],'2':[],'3':[],'4':[],'5':[],'6':['5'],'7':['1'],'8':['6','9','0'],'9':['3','5'],'0':[],'+':['-'],'-':[],'=':['-']}

adds = {'1':['7'],'2':[],'3':['9'],'4':[],'5':['6','9'],'6':['8'],'7':[],'8':[],'9':['8'],'0':['8'],'+':[],'-':['+'],'=':[]}

noop = {'1':[],'2':['3'],'3':['2','5'],'4':[],'5':['3'],'6':['9','0'],'7':[],'8':[],'9':['6','0'],'0':['9','6'],'+':['='],'-':[],'=':['+']}

ts = list("37+32=55")
alt_strings = []

for i, c in enumerate(ts):
    for new_char in noop[c]:
        alt_strings.append(ts[:i]+[new_char]+ts[i+1:])

    for sub_c in subs[c]:
        for i2, c2 in enumerate(ts):
            for add_c in adds[c2]:
                s = [x for x in ts]
                s[i] = sub_c
                s[i2] = add_c
                alt_strings.append(s)

alt_strings = [''.join(x) for x in alt_strings]
print alt_strings

for alt_string in alt_strings:
    split_strings = alt_string.split('=')
    if len(split_strings) != 2:
        continue

    left = eval(split_strings[0])
    right = eval(split_strings[1])
    if left == right:
        print alt_string
```

The possible combinations I got were:

```
['27+32=55', '57+32=55', '91+32=55', '31+92=55', '31+32=65', '31+32=95', '31+32=56', '31+32=59', '37=32=55', '97-32=55', '37-92=55', '37-32=65', '37-32=95', '37-32=56', '37-32=59', '37+22=55', '37+52=55', '37+33=55', '37+32+55', '97+32-55', '37+92-55', '37+32-65', '37+32-95', '37+32-56', '37+32-59', '37+32=35', '37+32=53']
```

And there were no matches (hehe).

Comment: As with the above (Bennett's comment)...+1 for the _excellent pun_ (and the cool programming solution too, I guess

Comment: @tyobrien how would you make the first number a 67?

Comment: Oh nevermind. the digital is messing with me

Comment: Noop 3 can also turn into a 9, btw, if you don't have a segment on the bottom

Comment: Technically the '+' can be converted into a bitwise or '|', although I was also unable to find anything from that.

Comment: and 7 into 4. and how does 7->1 (I can see 11)?

Comment: and 5 to 9. thus my fabulous answer.

Comment: You can also remove the left vertical match from 7 to keep it as 7.

Comment: @1848 Did you see my answer? Bitwise OR works if you do 37 - 32 = 5 | 5

Answer (score 26):

> 37+32>55

There you go,

> just change the equals sign to a more than sign!

-edit

You take the

> **vertical** match from the plus sign

and

> use it to burn the first five in 55

to make

> 37 - 32 = 5

If only the first 5 would be a 6. That would help a lot. 
Please ask your sister for the solution and double check if it's actually possible. Because I have a hunch that this puzzle is impossible.

Comment: You need to move two matches to accomplish this; otherwise you end up with an implied greater than or equal sign which is also not true.

Comment: Greater than OR equal to, is true too.

Comment: Sorry about that, was a typo and it got cut-off. It is also true, but is not the full sign.

Comment: I figure you haven't read all the comments, but I've mentioned both of these in comments above. Great minds think alike I guess.

Comment: I like your second solution. It's not the inequality cheat, and you do move one match only, haha. +1 for that.

Answer (score 24):

I saw this in "hot network questions" and tried to solve it on paper before I clicked to avoid getting spoiled. So I scribbled down the equation. When I couldn't find a way to solve it, I finally opened the question and saw, that my 7 had one less matchstick (the very left one). So I wondered about the display of numbers we don't get to see. Would a 9 without an underscore be legal for example? It clearly would be a distinct nine, wheter the bottom stick is there or not. You wouldn't return your 80's alarm clock because of such a nine, anyway.

Along this line of thinking I came up with this solution:

> 37 + 32 = 69
>  by taking the bottom matchstick from the second five to make the first five a six. Granted, the resulting nine is somewhat weird, but you clearly would not assume another number instead of it. Maybe for arguments sake just now, but not if some hot girl wrote the nines of her phone number in that way. That would probably just be a-okay for you. So just give me the correct flag now. Thanks.

Comment: To further my point, here is a list of fonts in which the nines have no "back". This is from dafont.com and I just clicked through the scifi-section. https://imgur.com/a/8OuHuIB 
Occasionally (e.g. in font fabricate) you might mistake the five for a nine, but there is no way to confuse a nine with something else. 
As you can clearIy see: I really want this.

Comment: I get the feeling that this is most likely the correct solution, especially after reading the thread on twitter (see comments under OP's post). Since it's a Korean riddle I wouldn't put it past them to use numbers that look slightly differently.

Answer (score 21):

Ok here is one I don't think has appeared yet:

> $37-32=1^5 5$

Explanation:

> Take the vertical stick in the $+$ turning it into a $-$ and put left-below the first $5$ to get $_15\,5$. Interpret this as $1^55=5$.

Comment: This is my new favourite for applying more than simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 16):

Outside the box solution!

> Remove the match on the + to make it a -, then eat it. Then crop the picture so that it cuts out the last 5. 37 - 32 = 5, only one match (and the frame of the picture) has moved.

Comment: Great solution, although ...you eat matches?

Comment: I tell other people to eat matches. I find it improves my quality of life substantially.

Comment: Or even better rot13(yvtug gur zngpu naq ohea gur bgure 5)

Comment: @BennettBernardoni out of all the answers we've put forward, this one in the comments might be my favourite so far

Comment: Btw: rot13(Vs lbh vagraq gb pebc gur cvpgher naljnl lbh zvtug nf jryy zbir gur zngpu vagb gur ynfg svir vafgrnq bs rngvat vg, perngvat n fvk.)

Comment: rot13(Jul? Gung'f abg n inyvq rdhngvba...)

Comment: Vg'q or gur fnzr fbyhgvba nf lbhef, jvgu gur bayl qvssrerapr gung lbh jbhyqa'g unir gb rng bar bs gur zngpu fgvpxf.

Answer (score 12):

> Take a match from the equal sign and put it anywhere else where it creates a number. For example: 37 + 92 - 55. It's neither true nor false and it's left to the reader to calculate!

Comment: In fact, as the resulting expression is non-0 , many programming languages would say it is indeed `true`.

Answer (score 12):

The extra match on the 7 seems suspicious, so I assume the solution is:

> Removing the extra match from 7, breaking it in half and making it 69 in the other end:
>  [image]

Even better:

> If you can split the match vertically :)

Comment: From the comments: no splitting of the match!

Answer (score 9):

How about a hexadecimal answer?

> `17 + 3e = 55`

Of course, it makes a weird looking one...

> ```
> _  _      _  _      _  _
>  || | _|_ _||_| -- |_ |_
> _|  |  |  _||_  --  _| _|
> ```

Comment: Make sure to hide your answer in spoiler quotes `>!`, but $(+1)$ anyway :)

Comment: I tried to hide it, but no amount of >! and <pre><code> tags would allow the code block to remain lined up in the spoiler quote. Is there a good way of doing that?

Comment: There you go @BM-: note the `\\`s which stop italicisation.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, I hadn't though of that.

Answer (score 6):

My answer, similar to @alto's, is a little bit more elegant.

> Take the leftmost downstroke from the 7 and place it at an *angle above and and touching the top bar of the = sign* to form  'a greater-than-or-equal' (or less-than-or-equal") sign.

BTW, this brute force & ignorance approach (in Python 3.x.) shows that it is not possible without modifying the + or = chararacter:

```
'''  Dictionary of all possible "matchstick' substitutions.  Note that
     some "matchstick" characters can be transformed into variants of 
     themselves by adding or removing one stroke/matchstick, e.g. 7 (by removal of 
     leftmost downstroke); 6 and 9 (by adding a horizontal top/bottom stroke).    

SubstitutionList = {
                    '+':['+','-'',='], '-':['+','-'',='],     '=':['+','-'',='],
                    '1':['1'],         '2':['2','3','6'],     '3':['2','3',5','9'], 
                    '4':['4','9'],     '5':['3','5','6','9'], '6':['6','9','0'],
                    '7':['4','7','9'], '8':['8'],             '9':['9','6','0'], 
                    '0':['0','9','6'], 
'''     
''' Only these values are needed (after allowing for character variations) '''

SubstitutionList = { '2':['2','3','6'],     '3':['2','3','5','9'],
                     '5':['3','5','6','9'], '7':['4','7','9'], 
                     '+':['+','-','='],     '-':['+','-','='],
                     '=':['+','-','='] }

TestEquation = '37+32=55'    
PossibleSolutions = []   # None yet

''' For clarity the code that extracts values from "TestEquation" has been omitted  '''

for I in SubstitutionList.get( '3' )  : 
    for J in SubstitutionList.get( '7' ) :
        for K in SubstitutionList.get( "+" ) : 
            for L in SubstitutionList.get( "3" ) :
                for M in SubstitutionList.get( "2" ) :
                    for N in SubstitutionList.get( "=" ) :
                        for O in SubstitutionList.get( "5" ) :
                            for P in SubstitutionList.get( "5" ) :                                    
                                Equation = I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P    # concatinate the letters into a string
                                FirstNumber  = int( Equation[   : 2 ] )
                                SecondNumber = int( Equation[ 3 : 5 ] )
                                ThirdNumber  = int( Equation[ 6 :   ] )
                                if ( (Equation[2] == '=' ) and (Equation[5] == '+' ) ) :                                        
                                    if ( FirstNumber  == (SecondNumber + ThirdNumber) ) :
                                        PossibleSolutions += [ Equation ]                                   
                                elif ( (Equation[2] == '=' ) and (Equation[5] == '-' ) ) : 
                                    if ( FirstNumber  == (SecondNumber - ThirdNumber)  ) :
                                        PossibleSolutions += [ Equation ]
                                elif ( (Equation[2] == '+' ) and (Equation[5] == '=' ) ) :                                         
                                     if ( (FirstNumber + SecondNumber) == ThirdNumber  ) :
                                        PossibleSolutions += [ Equation ]
                                elif ( (Equation[2] == '-' ) and (Equation[5] == '=' ) ) :                                         
                                     if ( (FirstNumber - SecondNumber) == ThirdNumber ) :
                                        PossibleSolutions += [ Equation ]

OneCharacterMoves = []   # match changed position inside one character, e.g. change "3' to '2', "6" to "9" etc. 
TwoCharacterMoves = []   # match moved from one character to another
for ValidEquation in PossibleSolutions :   # valid solutions change one or two characters
    DifferenceCount = 0  
    for i, _ in enumerate( ValidEquation ) :
         if ValidEquation[ i ] != TestEquation[ i ] :
            DifferenceCount += 1                
    if ( DifferenceCount == 1 ) :  
        OneCharacterMoves += [ ValidEquation ]
    elif ( DifferenceCount == 2 ) :
        TwoCharacterMoves += [ ValidEquation ]

print( 'Original :                ', TestEquation )
print( 'Involving One Character:  ', OneCharacterMoves )        
print( 'Involving Two Characters: ', TwoCharacterMoves )
```

The program produces :

```
Original :                 37+32=55
Involving One Character:   []
Involving Two Characters:  ['27+32=59', '37+22=59', '37+32=69']
```

Inspecting the values shows that none of them can be produced by moving one matchstick.

Comment: It could well be argued, that the substitution-list is incomplete. Check out my answer or this font
https://www.dafont.com/de/space-age.font?fpp=100&text=1234567890
and run it again to be amazed!

Comment: I'm assuming we are limited to 7 segment "characters' - like the numbers on digital clocks., The code was inspired by @John Aaron.  And of course I may have missed some "subtitutions" . Neat font  by the way...

Comment: yeah, sure. my nine would be a AFGC in that regard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display_character_representations
Wikipedia basically says "uncommon", I say "weird", but I found eight fonts that use this style of nine and in no one it could be confused with something other... I am totally going to build a picture!

Comment: Changing two matches you can also get 97-32=65

Answer (score 6):

What about:

> [image: Match picture]

You can either interpret that as a zero or a five that's been slashed out.

Answer (score 6):

My contribution to the answer pile:

> Take the upper left match on the 7 so that it's still a 7. Put the match on top of the equals sign, so that it and the upper part of the equals sign form an angle. Like this:
>  
>  [image]

The result looks a bit sloppy, but it can be read as

> $37+32 \geq 55$

The inequality is technically correct, which is the best kind of correct.

Comment: \*Technically\*, the equation is not technically correct, it is the (rot13) \*vardhnyvgl* which is correct.

Comment: @boboquack Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

Along the lines of El-Guest and Alto:

> 37 + 3P = 55 where P = 6.

I know that's not the answer, however; from my testing I have found that the only (to my knowledge) possible (true) combinations are:

> 37 + 22 = 59, 27 + 32 = 59, 57 - 22 = 35, 97 - 32 = 65, 34 + 22 = 56

But all of those require more than one match. I'll keep at it, if I solve it I'll update. All in all, I have found `210` total numeric combinations. None of which are achieved with a single move. I have written a loop in `C#` that goes through multiple arrays of all possible number combinations to confirm this. I may be missing something, but mathematically; this seems quite impossible, aside from the *Cheater-Pants, you can't do that solutions* that *El-Guest* and several others (including myself) have posed.

Also, not sure as to why I got a down vote as my answer evaluates true, **and** can be achieved with a single match:

> 37 + 3P = 55 evaluates true when P = 6; this breaks down to 37 + 18 = 55.

If you down vote, please explain why the down vote is justified.

Comment: I like this answer, and thanks for the kind mention! :P (+1) from me!

Comment: I liked your reference, so no problem on the mention! Your answer was the first I thought of, then several other answers that fell into the same category. I only answered because my solution had not been recommended yet, and I hadn't found any possible numeric combinations!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a boolean logic solution:

> Take one of the $=$ matches, break it in half, and put it on the right side of the remaining = match to make a right facing arrow $\rightarrow$. Then, the LHS is $69$, interpreted as a boolean is True, and the RHS is $55$, interpreted as a boolean is True. Then, the statment True $\rightarrow$ True is True. Thus, the statement becomes True.

Answer (score 5):

I think the following is technically a solution to the problem:

> Make use of the fact that those are not arbitrary sticks, but matches. So, take the vertical match from the plus (making it a minus), move it quickly over the side of the match box (so it starts burning), and then move it in turn to all the matches making up the left digits (so they all catch fire and burn away, without moving). Then put that match anywhere out of the way to finish its burning without affecting the rest of the matches.
>
>  The remaining matches form the equation 7-2=5.

Comment: Or use your idea to burn the first 5: 37 - 32 = 5.

Answer (score 5):

The solution appears after [re]moving a match:

> 37 - 32 = 5
> [image: solution]
>  a clue is that in second `5` match heads are aligned so that they burn each other properly until `5` is fully burnt, so perhaps we are supposed to ignite it with the match we took away.

Comment: This is a good observation: the first 5 is drawn differently to the other numbers in that its heads are together, whereas the others are apart. Could be onto something

Answer (score 5):

By moving one match to

> turn the second 5 into 3 *and* then interpreting the suspicious "extra" match in 7 as 1

we get

> 3<sup>1</sup>7+32=53

Answer (score 4):

It gives a negative value but I would like to share it anyways:

> 37-92 = 55

How?

> Just remove the vertical match from the "+" sign and add onto 32, now it is 92.

Comment: Where does the - in front of 55 come from?

Comment: @puck it’s not a match.. it’s negative value (-)

Comment: the result is -55 not 55. To make the term match you need a minus sign in front of 55.

Comment: I like it even if it's not correct. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution exploiting that the algebraic operations are not specified in the question.

> Take the vertical part of the plus sign and place it horizontally above the equality sign to obtain 37 "minus" 32 "is defined as" 55.

Comment: That's not the symbol for "is defined as" ... ?

Comment: it is used as such, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar

Comment: Nice. The brute-force general-case approach.

Answer (score 3):

> Move the lower match of the plus and the top match moves too! Make $37\times32=1184=550\times2+84$, and the picture has been (unfairly in my opinion) cropped so that you can't see the last bit!

Comment: Are you claiming that "0×2+84" is missing from the right part of the image? That's quite a bold claim.

Comment: JonMark Perry; do you have any evidence of this? Perhaps an online sample, or the original image itself?

Comment: it later struck me the cropped portion could be anything, $\times21+29$, for example, so no direct proof yet...

Answer (score 3):

To combine user477343's comment with CR241's answer,

> Remove the vertical match from the +, break it in half, put one half on the upper left of the first 3 to make it a 9, and the other half in front of the first 5 as a minus sign.
>
>  [image: Illustration]

I know the way I constructed this pattern doesn't match the original picture, but I'm sure I nailed the right pattern.

Comment: OP specifically says, [albeit in comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69885/make-3732-55-correct-by-moving-one-match#comment209243_69885) "don't break the match"

Comment: @Tas Yes, so it does. *sigh*

Comment: Oh, kind of you to include me in your answer! $(+1)$ :P

Answer (score 3):

The equation is actually

> $$3^1 7 + 32 = 55$$

So,

> $$3^1 \times 7 + 32 = 53$$ ...just turn the $55$ into a $53$ by moving one match.

---

Edit: Sorry, I didn't notice that Kamil posted the same answer earlier.

Comment: Excellent - this looks to be it!

Comment: @Tom couldn't agree more! Unfortunately, however, this is a duplicate of [**KamilMaciorowski**'s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69885/make-3732-55-correct-by-moving-one-match/70293#70293) :\

Comment: @user477343 - good spot! Kamil posted this earlier. These solutions resolve the suspicious 1 before the 7 and give a valid equation. Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

> Remove the lower right matchstick to give 3 to the power of pi. Break the stick a bit and  the extra matchstick on the equals to give an approximately equals symbol.

Comment: That's two operations (removing one matchstick, breaking another), but the question requires just one.

Comment: No it does not seem to mention anything about number of operations. Only one stick is bent. But then a comment says no match breaking.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of

> $ 37 - 32 ≡ 55 \pmod{5}$

I have

> moved the vertical bar of the $+$ sign moved to the $=$ sign to get a triple bar symbol. This turns the expression into a [modular arithmetic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).